# Build bitcoin-qt.exe on ubuntu 18.4

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, ubuntu, windows, compiling

0.8.1 version and when i compile this version but successfully compiled but now i want to generate the window executable file(.exe) from bitcoin-0.8.1 version. so latest version and older bitcoin-0.8.1 version have big difference in new version they have depends folder and other all file from where we can get exe file for new version but in bitcoin-0.8.1 how i can generate window executable file mean exe file please help me if anyone knows about this thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find the build intructions for the Windows version of 0.8.1 by searching the Bitcoin Core repository at the v0.8.1 tag:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.8.1/doc/build-msw.txt

It says "releases are cross-compiled using mingw running on Linux".

Comment: I saw that but i dont understand how to do that on linux it seems that the cammand are for win folder strukture is there any tutorrial to make it on ubuntu?

Comment: Is it only that code for linux? "Bitcoin
-------
DOS prompt:
cd \bitcoin\src
mingw32-make -f makefile.mingw
strip bitcoind.exe"